# Manually award the tag synonomizer badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, tag-synonyms

There is a fair amount of tag synonyms that are created via the child meta (in fact, looking at the tag synonyms page, the vast majority of the synonyms are done by the mods).

**Examples:**

- [Merge [video-conversion] → [video-converter]](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4104/merge-video-conversion-video-converter)
- [Synonymize [ahk] with [autohotkey]](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4066/synonymize-ahk-with-autohotkey)
- [Merge the tag "test" with the tag "testing"](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3939/merge-the-tag-test-with-the-tag-testing)

Why should the users that get a [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) on their post not get the badge, just because they suggested the synonym in a different place?

Perhaps this badge should be awarded when a user has a post tagged [tag-synonym](/questions/tagged/tag-synonym) and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)?

Comment: Yet another symptom of the synonym-proposal mechanism being useless/nigh-invisible :P

Comment: Trying to vote for obvious synonyms usually fails for lack of rep on that specific tag. More or less makes it a mod-only feature.